# How to serialize and deserialize a class with byte array as a member in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to send data between 2 process in the form of byte streams, which is working fine for almost all the classes but one problem i am having is that the deserilization fails if the class of the object has a byte array inside it and gives me an error stating the assembly where the serilization took place cannot be loaded.  I cannot include the assembly in here because both sender and receiver  are different applications.

Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit: Sorry it turns out that even normal classes cannot be deserialized in the other end**

**Edit: And one of the applications out of the 2 uses .Net 2.0**

```
public static byte[] SerializeToByteArray(this object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] byteArray) where T : class
{
    if (byteArray == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        memStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);s
        var obj = (T)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: which form of serialization do you use?
Please add some source code to illustrate your situation

Comment: I am using memmory stream to serialzie and deserialize.....

Comment: BinaryFormatter requires exact version of assembly where classes to be serialized/deserialized defined. You need to switch to another form of serialization

Comment: You could use one assembly with you datatypes that you want to use in both applications. Perhaps serialisation can be solved in that assembly, too.

Comment: hey sorry for late reply, that is what i did and it works fine now!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd propose you to use [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (this MSDN link also have example of how class should be decorated with attributes).

Then you can (de)serialize such class to/from binary form easily:

```
public static byte[] SerializeToByteArray<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] byteArray) where T : class
{
    if (byteArray == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
        var obj = (T) serializer.ReadObject(memStream);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

> use `return default(T);` instead of `return null;` , because T might be *non-nullable*
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default

[**Update**] Warning! this is still not the best solution, as you'll have to define totally equal classes in both applications and pass them as generic parameter to these functions

**[EDIT]**
Since you have to use .net 2.0 then you need to fall back to XMLSerialization. It's not as convenient as DataContract serialization, but it should work. Here is [starting page for this topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx)
Below is code for serialization/deserialization

```
public static byte[] SerializeToByteArray<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(this byte[] byteArray) where T : class
{
    if (byteArray == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i need the number of classes to be exactly same, there is not problems there.

The real problem is one of those application runs on .Net 2.0. And as far as I have checked it doesnt have the support for DataContractSerializer class

Comment: and sorry for less detailed question